# Why we use context-free grammar for parsing?

Tags: compilers, parsers

Why we use context-free grammar for parsing? Why not regular expression and not context-sensitive grammar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because regular expressions are too weak and context-sensitive languages are too difficult to parse. More specifically, regular expressions can't specify that the brackets in your program match up; determining whether a string matches a context-sensitive language is **PSPACE**-complete (so probably takes exponential time).